# How to whitelist Facebook app to send private inbox message by graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message, whitelist, inbox

There have many people asking around how to send private inbox message by graph api, i search for long time, the answer is no. the reason is "App must be on whitelist"

Alternate solution is send by chat api (xampp). but this is not my solution. coz html message is not supported in chat api.

I know dropbox can do it, may i ask how to whitelist my app in Facebook to send inbox message?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirement for an app that I am developing and I haven't been able to find any explicit directions on how to get onto the "white list".

However, my suspicion is that you need to apply to get into the [Preferred Marketing Developer Program](http://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/)

At least, this is what Facebook says you need to do to get white listed to use the Ads API:

The Ads API is a restricted platform which may only be accessed by whitelisted Apps. You can learn more about the program and apply online. You need to apply separately for each app.

Answer (score 1):

I am also struggling with this question for a while now.

I've posted my question on the facebook.stackoverflow.com site: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13587441/facebook-invite-friends-functionality-for-multiple-recipients-custom-message

Isn't there any way of handling this issue? Help is highly appreciated!